# Invisible captcha does not work in Chrome Lite mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cache-control, invisible-recaptcha

I have implemented Google's invisible recaptcha on my js app.
https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible
It works fine on desktop and on incognito in mobile but on mobile if my lite mode is on, the captcha script throws an error as (it works fine on mobile incognito)
`Could not connect to the reCAPTCHA service.Please check your internet connection and reload to get a reCAPTCHA challenge.`
Even tried
`cache-control: no-transform`
but no luck.
Has anyone else faced the same issue.Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: We can disable the lite mode on Chrome but cannot ask customers to do the same when the application is being used by 1k-5k customers in a month.

Answer (score 0):

We faced the same issue raised a bug for this but there has been no movement on it for 8 months https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1099269